# How are register detail figures made for IP/peripheral documentation?

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, documentation, peripheral

How are the register detail figures made for documentation of things like Xilinx/Vivado IP or  in documentation for memory-mapped peripherals in microcontrollers like the examples below?

[Xilinx IP documentation](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/pg021_axi_dma/MM2S_DMACR-MM2S-DMA-Control-Register-Offset-00h)

[image: Xilinx IP example]

[ESP32 documentation](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s2_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf#page=285)

[image: ESP32 example]

I'm trying to write my own documentation for IP I made, but I'm finding it difficult to replicate something similar.

Comment: These can get complicated, so I won't give an answer, but I would use tikz in LaTex for this.

Comment: You can do this in word if you wanted.

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to do using e.g. Inkscape or even Word.

Comment: Personally I hate maintaining register documentation by hand. Most register generation frameworks come with a documentation component, check out rggen or cheby. Wavedrom also has a register feature.

Comment: Use any application you know to produce images, then include that image in your text. For example, I prefer UMLet for UML and general diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Use any application you know to produce images, then include that image in your text.

You might also want to learn to use your text processing program. Many of them offer simple graphical objects. And all of the text processing programs are capable to insert images in your text.